# Does Outlook oft templates support CSS media-queries

Tags: outlook, media-queries, office365, html-email, email-templates

I'm asking if the Outlook oft templates files support media-queries.

I'm using exactly the Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0) 64-Bit and I don't find anywhere if this version supports CSS media-queries for HTML E-mail templates or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook 2007-2019, outlook.com,  do not support `@media` queries. Outlook mobile supports them.

A full list of what is supported by various Outlook clients and other email clients can be found at:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/

Good luck.

Comment: The campaign monitor site is not necessarily up to date. The other one to watch (also not necessarily up to date...) is https://www.caniemail.com